# How to include Smarty 3 into Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, smarty

I am new to Laravel, so still getting used to the concepts, however I have around 10 years of experience using Smarty. So I wish to capitalize on that (apart from the fact that Blade seems to lack too many features I find useful and ready out of the box in Smarty, but anyway besides the point of this question).

I have been looking around to find the right way of using Smarty in Laravel, and although on a few forums such as [here](http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=9188) it seems to be possible its not clear what I need to do to use it properly within the framework. More concretely my questions are:

1. Which Composer package should I include in my `composer.json`? There seems to be [this](https://github.com/lukeforeman/Laravel4-SmartyView) which includes Smarty itself, because it was modified (not too keen about that). And [here](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=85950&sid=2eb2c4fe48681d7666e2be4e45659837) they also suggest http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/SmartyView. Not sure if it is the same, because the bundles sub-domain of laravel.com isn't even coming up. It used to come up a few days ago, but I don't know if they turned it off because bundles are now obsolete and replaced by packages... not sure. There is also [this](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/latrell/smarty)
2. How should I configure Laravel to use Smarty views instead of Blade views?
3. Given that Laravel uses REST style pretty URLs, how should I include CSS and JS files from Smarty 
   views, such that the path to them is dynamically set by Laravel? In Blade you do something like: `{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}`. Can I use something similar? Or better still set a template variable from the code by calling the HTML class? (I don't really like calling PHP code within templates that should just be doing presentation logic.)

Sorry if some questions are a bit trivial.

Comment: I think you should try Blade. I also have big experience with Smarty templates but now I'm also learning Laravel and using Blade with it. In fact almost all templates systems do the same and some of them have more functions then the other but it's almost always enough to generate desired output

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek Thanks. I have been trying it a little but the syntax is horrible, inconsistent at times, and so confusing and broken up (templates vs layouts and all that) that its going to be difficult to be used by web designers. With discipline Smarty templates are nearly loadable even in tools like Dreamweaver.

Comment: Just a heads up, there is a reason blade was put in over smarty. You're most likely going to have to tear laravel apart to implement it.

Comment: @castis It seems that the main reason was before Laravel adopted a lot of the Symfony components (where Twig is the preferred template engine) a quick and simple template engine was needed, and Blade was created.... at least from the limited research I have done so far. In the meantime I am having a go at this http://packalyst.com/packages/package/latrell/smarty

Comment: If switching template engines would break Laravel, then Laravel is broken; Luckily, judging by the posted answer, it's also untrue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

OK so after some more research, I managed to painlessly integrate Smarty 3 within Laravel 4. I am not sure if it is the best way, but its working perfectly, so open to comments or further suggestions.

I installed [this](http://packalyst.com/packages/package/latrell/smarty) Smarty View for Laravel and followed the instructions to add it in the list of `providers` in `app/config/app.php`. After running the `php artisan config:publish latrell/smarty` command the configuration was automatically created and I was ready to go. This package also seems to use the proper Smarty libraries rather than some modified templates.

I then just created a plain old HTML file, with a `.tpl` extension in the `app/views` directory, and a corresponding controller in the `app/controllers` directory, together with the corresponding route in `routes.php` and hey presto, it worked without a hitch.

I even modified the BaseController to maintain a common list of template variables (such as the CSS styles etc.) to inject in the HTML without putting ugly PHP code in the template. (I don't know if there's a better way to set them directly into the `View` from the `BaseController` rather than expecting the sub-class to pass them in the call to the `make` method, but I guess thats a different question.)

Code below for who might need it:

`HelloWorld.tpl`

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    {$style}
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1>Hello {$name}</h1>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

`BaseController.php`

```
class BaseController extends Controller {

    protected $template_vars = array();

    protected function addTemplateVar($key, $value)
    {
        $this->template_vars[$key] = $value;
    }

    /**
     * Setup the layout used by the controller.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function setupLayout()
    {
        //not sure if I need this any more since I am using Smarty
        if ( ! is_null($this->layout))
        {
            $this->layout = View::make($this->layout);
        }

        $this->addTemplateVar("style", HTML::style("css/bootstrap.css"));
    }

}
```

`HelloWorldController.php`

```
class HelloWorldController extends BaseController 
{          
    public function showHelloWorld()
    {
        $this->addTemplateVar('name', 'World!');
        return View::make('helloworld', $this->template_vars);
    }
}
```

In `routes.php`:

```
Route::get('helloworld', 'HelloWorldController@showHelloWorld');
```

Hope its useful for someone else.

Comment: +1 for solution. May be useful for someone in future

Comment: Note that there is an issue with Smarty in composer (packagist) at the moment. `composer update` breaks at the moment with Smarty 3.1.20 due to a mistake in its `composer.json`. There is a fix already but its not on the stable branch yet.