# Handlebars - Using Partial View

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, viewengine

I am new in [Express.JS](https://expressjs.com/) and [Handlebars.JS](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js#differences-between-handlebarsjs-and-mustache) and trying to build an app on `"express": "~4.14.0"` and `"hbs": "~4.0.0"`.

I was familiar with [Laravel Blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) as a template engine.

There are some features like-

1. [Extending A Layout](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/extending-multiple-blade-hierarchy)
2. [Add Section in a Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615793/laravel-blade-how-to-append-to-a-section)
3. [Implement and including Partial Views](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/90/including-a-blade-template-within-another-template)

But I am not able to find them from-

> https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js#differences-between-handlebarsjs-and-mustache

or

> http://handlebarsjs.com/

Actually is there any way for them?

**If yes**, can anyone please give me a way or documentation on how can I do that.

**If not**, then can anyone suggest what view engine will be better in [Express.JS](https://expressjs.com/) to do that?

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: http://handlebarsjs.com/partials.html, maybe this helps?

Comment: Hi, I already checked that, but could not find a way to use for my requirement. Can u please help?

Comment: I have never worked with Handlebars partials views, but I will have a look.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't find anything that you might have missed, you should be able to do it with the link I send.

Comment: Sorry to say, I am unable to find similarity. So, if u go to the link I have provided and your link and provide the similarity, that would be appriatiated @DavidWestern ?