# Laravel blade: Template not rendering

Tags: php, laravel, view, frameworks, laravel-blade

This one works fine which is found in my pages folder in the view folder

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <h2>This is an awesome application. My about page.</h2>
    <p>It is very awesome that I am coding it with laravel</p>
@endsection
```

I had to use @include rather than @extend. This worked after it was pointed out to use @include.

While this one doesn't which is found in my post folder in the view folder

```
@include('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <a href="/posts" class="btn btn-default">Go Back</a>
    <h1>{{ $post->title}}</h1>
    <p>{{ $post->body}}</p>
    <small>{{ $post->created_at }}</small>
@endsection
```

Comment: What's wrong? What is the *Error*?

Comment: instead of  `@include('layouts.app')` put `@extends('layouts.app')`

Comment: Thanks @parthu_panther. That was the problem.

Comment: @SandOfVega it was showing a blank page but took into account the included file but not the content.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [laravel blade, how to append to a section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26615793/laravel-blade-how-to-append-to-a-section)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `@include` use `@extends`

Also try closing your `<p>` tag with `</p>` and `<small>` tag with `</small>`

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <a href="/posts" class="btn btn-default">Go Back</a>
    <h1>{{ $post->title}}</h1>
    <p>{{ $post->body}}</p>
    <small>{{ $post->created_at }}</small>
@endsection
```

Comment: Thanks. The @includes was the problem.